# Curency Rate Conversion Wrong Base Currency

Tags: python

I need a currency rate update script, but I have the following problem
If I call the interface, I get the following response:

```
"base": "USD",
"rates": {
"AED": 3.672782,
"AFN": 57.680075,
"ALL": 130.5485,
"AMD": 477.866,
"ANG": 1.78952,
"EUR": 0.927815,
"AOA": 107.13525,
```

...

The Problem is, I need the currency rate conversion in EUR. That means, my base rate is USD, but I need it in EUR.

Is there any option to calculate from this JSON the currency rates with base rate USD to currency rates with base rate EUR.

Comment: This is a trivial calculation, what exactly is your problem with it? If $1 = €0.927815, then €1 = ...?

Comment: Dies the `rates` table also include an entry `"USD": 1.0,`?

Comment: For arbitrary conversions you just do two steps CURR1 => USD then USD => CURR2.  It would seem pretty straight forward to encapsulate that into a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
rates = {
    'AED': 3.672782,
    'AFN': 57.680075,
    'ALL': 130.5485,
    'AMD': 477.866,
    'ANG': 1.78952,
    'EUR': 0.927815,
    'AOA': 107.1352,
    'USD': 1.0 } # base in rates needed to convert to/from base
```

`rates` can be used to support arbitrary conversions:

```
def convert_currency(rates, value, src_curr, dest_curr):
    return value / rates[src_curr] * rates[dest_curr]
```

In use:

```
>>> convert_currency(3.50, 'ANG', 'EUR')
1.81465001788189
>>> convert_currency(1.00, 'USD', 'EUR')
0.927815
```

To change `rates` to a new base do:

```
def rates_with_new_base(rates, old_base, new_base):
    new_rates = {curr: rate/rates[new_base] for curr, rate in rates.items()}
    # only needed if old base was not in rates table
    new_rates[old_base] = 1.0 / rates[new_base]
    return new_rates
```

In use:

```
>>> rates_with_new_base(rates, 'USD', 'EUR')
{'AED': 3.9585283704186724,
 'AFN': 62.16764656747305,
 'ALL': 140.70531302037583,
 'AMD': 515.0444862391748,
 'ANG': 1.9287465712453453,
 'AOA': 115.47043322214019,
 'EUR': 1.0,
 'USD': 1.0778010702564629}
```

Comment: But from where do i get the value? I don't know the USD Currency, because in the json it's just 1.
I have to save the daily rates. But not with USD as base rate  in need EUR as base rate. So i need all currency rates as EUR Rate. 
The file should be:

'AND': 'X EUR',
'UD': 'X EUR',
...

Comment: Whatever your base is add it to your rates table.  If you never want to convert to or from the base you don't need to add it.  The base currency is always `"base_currency_name": 1.0`.  If you can't do that, change the return statement to `return value / (1.0 if src_curr == 'USD' else rates[src_curr]) * (1.0 if dest_curr = 'USD' else rates[dest_curr])`.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I misunderstand your intention, but I believe you are asking for a USD to EUR conversion function:

```
def convert(usd, cur):
    rates = {
    "AED": 3.672782,
    "AFN": 57.680075,
    "ALL": 130.5485,
    "AMD": 477.866,
    "ANG": 1.78952,
    "EUR": 0.927815,
    "AOA": 107.13525,
    }
    return usd*rates[cur.upper()]
```

As such:

```
   convert(5, 'aed')
=> 18.363909999999997
   convert(5, 'aoa')
=> 535.67624999999998
   convert(5, 'eur')
=> 4.6390750000000001
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a dictionary of rates,

```
 rates_usd = {"base": "USD", "rates": { "AED": 3.672782, "AFN": 57.680075, "ALL": 130.5485, "AMD": 477.866, "ANG": 1.78952, "EUR": 0.927815, "AOA": 107.13525}}
```

you can transform these values to a new base currency with,

```
def conversion(rates, base="EUR"):
     out = {'base': base, 'rates': {}}
     scale = rates['rates'][base]
     out['rates']['USD'] = 1./scale
     for key, val in rates['rates'].items():
         out['rates'][key] = val/scale
     return out

conversion(rates_usd, 'EUR')
# {'base': 'EUR',  'rates': {'AED': 3.9585283704186724,   'AFN': 62.16764656747305,   'ALL': 140.70531302037583,   'AMD': 515.0444862391748,   'ANG': 1.9287465712453453,   'AOA': 115.47048711219371,   'EUR': 1.0,   'USD': 1.0778010}}
```